# How to display facebook status feed on website with PHP? (similar to twitter feeds)

Tags: php, facebook

I've been looking all over for a way to do this, and I'm still rather stumped.

What I'd like to do is have a facebook status feed alongside my twitter feed (see footer of [this page](http://www.zensavona.com)), but cant seem to find a way of doing this without creating an app to convert my statuses to RSS then reading the RSS in PHP. which gets messy and complicated. Surely there is an easier way (other than facebook's supplied iframe status box).

Thanks in advance.

Zen

Comment: Hi, did you able to get the result? If so can you share it here?

Comment: see below, I used the facebook graph API (read at http://developer.facebook.com). its pretty easy to figure out.

Comment: If your client wants a "little more" custom design, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10968011/599082

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

"Facebook Query Language, or FQL, enables you to use a SQL-style interface to query the data exposed by the Graph API."

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Query with the viewer_id as your facebook UID, then parse the returned XML or JSON and integrate it into your twitter feed chronologically with the created_time field.

BTW, you need to get the appropriate keys for authorization by getting your developer key and your profile's access token. Since you probably want more than your public profile (maybe?) you need to request extended permissions for your profile.

Comment: this does exactly what I want it to. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Facebook's Social Plugins. It allows you to display widgets with a single line of HTML code...very easy to setup.

Check out: http://developers.facebook.com/plugins

Comment: I specifically mentioned that I was looking for an alternative to that :) but thanks for the input. I want to style the posts as i wish, similar to what you can do with twitter.