# Facebook: querying public events without requiring users to be logged in?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-access-token

So I am confused on the new FB requirements for querying public events(for instance getting the start time), and it seems I am not the only one, even Facebook's own examples no longer work.....

Anyway, I would like to be able to query some public events and display the information on my site without requiring the user to be logged into facebook(since the information is public, that should be possible, since if I go directly to the Facebook page while logged out of Facebook, I can see all the information I want to query), but this doesn't seem possible to do(safely) on the client side anymore.

In order to use the graph API to query events an access token, either user, app, or page manager, is required.  But if the user is not logged in then obviously I cannot use their access token, and publishing my app or page manager access tokens is a recipe for disaster, so how can I query public event data on the client-side without requiring the user to log in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get a public Facebook page's feed using Graph API without asking a user to allow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373645/can-you-get-a-public-facebook-pages-feed-using-graph-api-without-asking-a-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Facebook Event API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) page:

> Starting July 5th, an access token will be required to access even
>   public events. To read an Event, you will need one of the following:
>
> a user access token for a user who can see the event an app access
>   token (for non-public events, must be the app that created the event)
>   a page access token (for non-public events, must be the page that
>   created the event)

Bummer, it looks like this policy was just revised a week or two ago. :-/