# How to "GET" Facebook page statuses via Graph API for mobile website

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, status, posts, mobile-website

I'm designing a mobile website for my church, and I would like to post my church's Facebook status updates on the website. I tried the Facebook like box, but I found it limited in functionality, and it doesn't work very well on a mobile website.

I then discovered Facebook's Graph API. I found a PHP script to use on my website (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373645/can-you-get-a-public-facebook-pages-feed-using-graph-api-without-asking-a-user), and I created an app on Facebook. Using Facebook's Graph API Express, I'm trying to customize the output so I ONLY obtain my page's status updates and timestamps.

For example, I tried https://graph.facebook.com/[profile ID]/posts. However, this includes when I posted pictures and created events; I only want status updates. Is there any way I can use Graph API to limit the posts by specifying the "type" as "status"? I can't get it to work.

Ideally, I want the code to get my church Facebook page's status updates, particularly the "message" and "created_time" fields, and I would like to limit the results to 10.

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know. I am a novice at this, and I'm basically just trying to find the code to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can use Graph API to limit the posts by specifying the "type" as "status"?

The Graph API includes a "statuses" endpoint as part of [the User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). It is accessed in a similar fashion as the "posts" endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[profile ID]/statuses
```

To limit the results to only 10 statuses, you could add a "limit" parameter to the URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[profile ID]/statuses?limit=10
```

For example, the page for Boo `facebook.com/boo` using an application access token.

```
<?php
$access_token = '1111111111|2Cha_1-n5';
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/Boo/statuses?limit=10&access_token=" 
    . $access_token;
$page_posts = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url), true);

foreach($page_posts['data'] as $post){
    $message = $post['message'];
    $post_time = $post['created_time'];
}

echo $message .' '. $post_time;
?>
```

More information on this and other ways to filter the API's output can be found in the [Graph API's Pagination documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/).

Comment: I obtained my app access token and used the above code verbatim, but I got this error, "
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ... on line 4"
Line 4 is the one where $graph_url is defined. Where did I go wrong?

`code`
<?php

$access_token = "00000000|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/martindalechristianfellowship/statuses?limit=10&access_token="
    . $access_token;
$page_posts = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url), true);

foreach($page_posts['data'] as $post){
    $message = $post['message'];
    $post_time = $post['updated_time'];
}

Comment: @NathanSchmitt The $graph_url variable definition is split across two lines, so there should be no semicolon at the end of line 4.

Comment: @NathanSchmitt you forgot to put semicolon at line 3