# Can I get Facebook wall posts in pure JavaScript without login?

Tags: javascript, facebook, web-applications, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Can I get Facebook wall posts without login if I don't use PHP or other backend code.

I have an application which needs to get Facebook wall posts. I want to do this task in pure JavaScript. It seems I have to ask users to login before seeing those posts, which is annoying for some people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your app's access token instead of current user's. However you shouldn't use this one on client side, because showing your app secret or app's access token in generated HTML is not safe, because they'll be able to use it. You have to get it on server side, the same with getting wall posts. Check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/) for info about app's access token. You may also find some tips in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373645/can-you-get-a-public-facebook-pages-feed-using-graph-api-without-asking-a-user) and answers. However, be sure to check the dates of answers and comments because some things in FB Api are changing in time and some may be outdated now.