# Facebook Graph API: Can't access the authorization token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**What I want** is to fetch data using of a public page. 
I tried the documentation, but wasn't able to find that information. Then I googled it and found this [Can you get a public Facebook page's feed using Graph API without asking a user to allow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373645/can-you-get-a-public-facebook-pages-feed-using-graph-api-without-asking-a-user) question here at stackoverflow and that perfectly explained what I want to do with PHP. I read in the **McNab's answer** that I need an app at facebook to fetch that data (to retrieve an access token). I created an app and it took me to the basic settings page where it gave me the **AppId** and the **AppSecret**. Now as from the McNab answer, I only need AppId and app secret to get the auth_token, I used the following code, but due to some reason I get `false` instead of the AuthToken. What am I doing wrong here? I didn't add any further details to the app, is it causing this problem, do I need to add further details to the app or is there anything else causing this?

P.S Also I am trying this on localhost on my PC.

```
function fetchUrl($url){

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

 $feedData = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch); 

 return $feedData;

}

$profile_id = "100002138417834";

// App info needed for auth.
$app_id = "--------------";
$app_secret = "-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-";

$authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");

var_dump($authToken);
```

**UPDATE:**

When I did `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` (as suggested in the comments), it gave me this error:

> string 'SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.
>   Details: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed'
>   (length=146)

Comment: It returning false means the cUrl failed, not so much the FB Api. Is error reporting on? Try `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` after curl_exec

Comment: If the returned value is `bool(false)` there was an error, so you should use `curl_error($ch)` to find out what it was. Alternatively, use `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` to enable debugging.

Comment: Does this mean you solved it?

Comment: @JaapMoolenaar no. I got busy. I am going to test the error now.

Comment: @JaapMoolenaar please check the question. I've updated it with the error that I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ssl certificate is not correctly validated. Curl used to be able do this properly when it was bundled with CA certificates. Either you point curl to the right certificate ( info here http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html ), or disable validating all together.

You can disable ssl certificate validating using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

*This is a very common curl problem, the answer to this is probably all over SO ;-)*

Comment: I solved it using my answer to this question, but your answer works as well (plus seems more easy) Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! You have a good way of handling questions and answers. Keep it up :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to output the error (thanks to @Jack) and I got this:

> string 'SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed' (length=146)

Seemed like a problem with SSL Certificate. So what I did was:

1. Downloaded a ca bundle from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).
2. Put that bundle in the same directory where I had this index.php file i.e. the file having the code.
3. Then set the CURLOPT_CAINFO option using curl_setopt() to point to that file (it must be absolute path).
4. Refreshed the page and it was working :)
5. Here is the line to be added:

   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__). '/cacert.pem');`

And the credit goes to @Jack who helped me in the chat :)