# Getting an image from a facebook post on a public page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to show a facebook feed on my website, which is working. But I only managed to show the text of the post, not the image attached to it (or if possible, if there are multiple images, only the first one or biggest one).

I tried looking [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post) for the correct name to get it using the API

This is my code now (which shows facebook posts in an owl carousel):

```
function fetchUrl($url){    
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
     // You may need to add the line below
     // curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

     $feedData = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch); 

     return $feedData;

    }

    //App Info, needed for Auth
    $app_id = "1230330267012270";
    $app_secret = "secret";

    //Retrieve auth token
    $authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=1230330267012270&client_secret=secret");

    $json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/267007566742236/feed?{$authToken}");

    $feedarray = json_decode($json_object);


    foreach ( $feedarray->data as $feed_data )
    {

        if($feed_data->message != ''){
            $facebookfeed .= '
                <div class="item">
                      <div class="product-item">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/siteimages/imgfacebook.jpg" alt="">
                            <h4 class="product-title">'.$feed_data->name.'</h4>
                            <p class="product-desc">'.$feed_data->message.'</p>
                            <p>'.$feed_data->story.'</p>
                            <img src="'.$feed_data->picture.'">
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lees meer</a></p>
                        </div><!-- Product item end -->
                </div><!-- Item 1 end -->';
        }
    }
echo $facebookfeed;
```

Looking at the Facebook documentation I thought `$feed_data->picture` would work, but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for your GET requests. For example, GET /v2.4/me/feed no longer includes likes and comments by default, but GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes will return the data.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: One last question: can I get all data from one curl? Or do I need two? I tried the following:`$json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/267007566742236/feed?fields=full_picture&{$authToken}");` But this stops any data from being returned.